# how to add tell a friend form in opencart v1.5.5

Tags: php, opencart

Can anybody tell me the working code example
for this query

how to add tell a friend form in opencart v1.5.5

Answer (score 1):

it's an extension. see http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=4348 for details or see [here](http://www.best-byte.com/tell-a-friend-form-oc-free-mod-opencart) where you can download it for free.

Comment: can u tell me .. how to put tell a friend link in main navigation

Comment: you have to edit catalog/view/theme/yourtheme/template/common/header.tpl